# Bootstrap and metro ui css javascript conflict

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

This might sound like a stupid question but I have had 2 days introducing problems and fixing them while trying to make my current app have the new metro ui css

I am pretty new to rails, and css as well.

I started with twitter bootstrap and included the sass gem. Then I stumbled across metro ui css and wanted to have that look and feel for my app. But by that time, I have implemented a lot of bootstrap look and feel and some of its elements which have javascript for ex. dropdown menus and accordians.

Now, I have installed metro ui css gem too. But now I see a lot of conflict and half of the things not working

Questions:
1. I guess somethings are not working for ex. accordion and dropdown menus because of javascropt conflict in bootstrap and metroui. Is it the correct reason?
2. Can I and should I use both of them together?
3. If I use bootstrap for my app and just copy the modern.css from metroui and go on without any problems or css will have some conflicts too.

I want to change the look and feel to metro ui css but without changing the bootstrap functionality. Should I stick to just one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are two libraries/frameworks for the same purpose, they are going to butt heads.

It's like putting two drivers in one car, It ain't gonna be easy to find a compromise!

My suggestion is to pick one you like and stick with it.

If you like the metro UI feel then use that, then look to bootstrap as inspiration on how to implement certain things.

Comment: Thanks Hailwood. I moved back to Bootstrap as there is lot of refactoring needed to move to micro ui css. But yes, it is a good learning for my next app. Thanks