# Using metro ui css in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, metro-ui-css

I am trying to use metro ui's button but it wont work.I think i have provided all the scripts and styles needed.I am new,Please help.

This is what i have done so far.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="metro.aspx.cs" Inherits="MetroWf.metro" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/metro-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/metro.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/metro/metro-button-set.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <button class="default" > helo </button>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives me a simple button.

Also i ma using vs13 so jquery already exist in my project.Does its presence makes difference in using metro.

And can i use metro and bootstrap side by side.I mean do the class name in them match and bring conflict.

**edit**
This is what i get no matter which class i use be it `default` or `danger`.

[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I get no error but it display the normal button.I mean using the class `default` or `danger` brings no change.

Comment: Shouldn't is be `class="btn btn-default"`?

Comment: I think that would be for bootstrap not metro any way i tried and nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `metro` class at the `<body>` So if you change it to `<body class="metro">` it should work. I have tested it on my local machine and it works like a gem. You can also refer to [Metro UI CSS](http://metroui.org.ua/)

Comment: well it worked thanks.I tried to implement the sidebar of Metro-ui according to `http://metroui.org.ua/sidebar.html`,the output goes well but the drop down wont function.Can u help?

Comment: When you say it doesn't function do you mean when you click on the `Sub Menu` it doesn't expand?

Comment: Yup thats the problem.

Comment: i have furthem more some subquestion in the above quesion.If you know can u please clearify me.

Comment: As far as I'm aware they will conflict with each other so you'll have to choose one of them. You can also refer to this question [Bootstrap and metro ui css javascript conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390399/bootstrap-and-metro-ui-css-javascript-conflict)